# I want to update a string in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, content_history with a column, doc_filename, and each row has a string value. Each string has a | and the portion in front of the | is a filepath. I want to replace that portion of the string with the correct filepath if it doesn't already match. What is the best way to go about doing this? Currently I use:

```
UPDATE content_history 
SET doc_filename = replace (doc_filename, 'path that needs to be replaced', 'new path') 
WHERE doc_filename LIKE 'old path%'
```

But if I don't have the exact path it doesn't replace so I have to run a select * query and manually go through and input all the different paths that are incorrect. It's not a viable long-term solution

Comment: you can use regex

Comment: You'd have to get more granular in your WHERE clause with a potential slew of OR's.  @T.S. SQL Server doesn't support regex, unfortunately.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You could export the rows - use a tool that does support regex to do the replace - and then reimport the rows. You decide how much effort you want to put into this and where your skills can be fully exploited. At least post a few sample rows showing different values  for "old path" and what they should be after your change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you wouldn't store multiple values as delimited values in a single value, you should have a separate column for each distinct value, then you wouldn't be asking such a question.

You can use `stuff`:

```
set doc_filename=Stuff(doc_filename, 1, CharIndex('|', doc_filename)-1, 'new path')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to split value to avoid an incorrect update

```
update CH
set CH.doc_filename = 'new_path' + '|' + P.right_part
from content_history CH
    outer apply
    (
        select left(CH.doc_filename, charindex('|', CH.doc_filename) - 1) as left_part
            ,right(CH.doc_filename, len(CH.doc_filename) - charindex('|', CH.doc_filename)) as right_part
        where charindex('|', CH.doc_filename) != 0
    ) P
where P.left_part = 'old_path'
```